# Create modifiable mail item from memorystream (oft file)

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook, memorystream

I have oft files stored in the database as binaries. Now I have to open the files so the user only has to click on send. But before this, I have to modify some attributes (To, message).

So how can I get a modifiable Mail Item from a MemoryStream?

**EDIT**

I'm open to solutions with other filetypes, I can change the binaries. The file just has to open in Outlook at the end.

Comment: What is an "oft file"?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot - `Application.CreateItemfromTemplate` only lets you specify a file based OFT file for one simple reason: there is common stream or other memory format that all languages that can use the Outlook Object Model can understand or provide.

Comment: Ok, If I have to I can also use other filetypes, see my edit.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking - what other file types?

Comment: I could also have the template text as .msg, .txt or any other filetype in the binaries. It just has to be a mail Item at the end so I can open it in Outlook for the user.

Comment: That would still be a file. It can of course be in your own format (e.g. XML), but then you would need to load it and parse, then explicitly create a new item and set all of its properties .